# Using solr shingle filter at query time

Tags: solr

I am trying to build a field in my Solr Schema which will be able to join words together at query time and then search for this new joined word in the index.

Lets say I have the word "bluetooth" in my index and I want this to come up in results when I search "blue tooth".

So far I have been unsuccessful in trying varying combinations of shinglefilterfactory and positionfilterfactory as well as keyword, standard and whitespace tokenizers.

I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is looking obscure to me and strange a little bit. But for your specific use-case the following filter can be used:

- `"solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"`
- `"pattern"="[\\W]"`
- `"replacement"=""`

It will make "blue tooth" to be replaced into "bluetooth". And also you can specify that field-analysis for query-time only.

But let me tell you that usually tokenization is used instead of concatenation. And let me also offer you the following filter - [WordDelimiterFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter). In such case this guy can split "BlueTooth" into "blue" and "tooth" based on cases.

Comment: Did some more investigation into this and it appears that becuase I'm using the edismax query parser, that splits the query by whitespace before it even gets to the tokenizer.